# NullPointerException when using FragmentActivity.getIntent().getExtras() on Android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, arguments, bundle, fragment

I'm starting to try using Android Fragments, especially to display Activities into a horizontal PagerAdapter.

Globally it works fine, but I have trouble passing arguments to my framgents and getting them back in the onCreateView() method.

Basically, I create my fragments like this :

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt(ActionCodes.GAME_INDEX, game.getIndex());
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, GameReadActivityFragment.class.getName(), args));
```

Notice that I pass the `Bundle` args to the Fragment.instantiate() method.

Then, in GameReadActivityFragment.onCreateView(), I do the following :

```
int gameIndex = this.fragmentActivity.getIntent().getExtras().getInt(ActionCodes.GAME_INDEX);
```

But I get a NullPointerException because `getExtras()` returns null :(

I searched for an answer but couldn't get my hand on one. I tend to think that I have to use something different from `getExtras()` to access this Bundle but I don't know what.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to put the code in onStart() of your fragment

Comment: I don't think that bundle is associated with any intent.  AFAIK, instantiating a fragment does not use an intent... (someone let me know if I'm misunderstanding this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do it like this:

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(String bar) {
        MyFragment frag = new MyFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("foo", bar);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }
```

Then in `onCreateView`, you can do:

```
String text = getArguments().getString("foo");
```